# IOS: property without ARC

Tags: ios, properties

I have a project with ARC but I disable it and now I have problem with properties as:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *frame;
```

now I have an error for "weak", what kind I can replace? retain?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to `weak` under manual reference counting is `assign`. Keep in mind, that unlike `weak` under ARC, the value of assign properties is *not* automatically zeroed when the instance pointed to by the property is deallocated. So, you need to be careful to discard assign references to objects before they're deallocated.

Why did you disable ARC?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace it with `assign`. And `strong` with `retain`. `retain` means the reference counter will be increased for every object stored there. And if you replace `weak` with `retain` you can get reference cycle and leak some memory.